# Can I replace start() join() by execute()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a set of threads that have to be run. At the first time I tried to loop through the threads and call start() and join() one by one. However, since I can't tell uses' CUP core, I noticed that if I use executed(), my program can be faster; but some threads are not implemented correctly.

Can I replace start() join() by execute()?

```java
for (Thread t:threads){
    t.start();
}
for (Thread t:threads){
    t.join();
}

//////////////////////////////////////
for (Thread t:threads){
    executor.execute(t);
}

((ExecutorService) executor).shutdown();
```

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc of [`ExecutorService.shtudown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()): _"This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use `awaitTermination` to do that."_ Also using `Thread` to submit tasks to an executor service makes no sense, use `Runnable`.

Comment: i get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have an ExecutorService, then you can use, [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) which will execute all of the tasks and wait for them to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed that if I use executed(), my program can be faster; but some threads are not implemented correctly.

Yeah there is some confusion here.  I doubt that your program is truly running "faster".

> Can I replace start() join() by execute()?

Although it would seem to work, this is a bug not the right thing to do.  You should be creating tasks that implement the `Runnable` and `Callable` interfaces which should be submitted to an `ExecutorService` with `threadPool.submit(...)`.  Your code is ~working because `Thread` implements `Runnable` but you are creating a thread instance but the thread that is really running your task is, very confusingly, from the thread-pool.  You should either do something like:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable());
// submit others
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

or do the threads by hand:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(my MyRunnable());
thread.start();
thread.join();
```

In most cases, the thread-pool version is recommended because you then don't have to manage the threads yourself.

Lastly, the difference between `threadPool.submit(...)` versus `threadPool.execute(...)` is that submit wraps the task and returns a `Future` which can return the results of `Callable` or a thrown exception.  If your task throws inside of an `execute(...)`, the thread is killed and a new thread will be started by the thread-pool.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to the callables in thread pool and I have them working properly. Thanks!